# How is PSZ Timestamp encoded in Bitcoin core code?

Tags: bitcoin-core, genesis-block, timestamp

In Chainparams.cpp of the Bitcoin Core source, the encoded `PSZTimestamp` is as follows

`04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73`

The original string is

`The Times 03/Jan/2009 Chancellor on brink of second bailout for banks`

If you convert that into `HEX` using any String to Hex converter online, you get

`5468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73`

And this is a substring of the `encoded PSZTimestamp` from the 16th character. My question:

**What are the first 16 character derived from?**
`04ffff001d010445`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73
```

The above is actually Bitcoin Script, not just byte data.

This breaks down to:

```
04         # PUSH the next 4 bytes
ffff001d   # This is the same as the nbits for the block, which was the target for the genesis block difficulty
01         # PUSH 1 byte
04         # PUSHed 1 byte - I'm not entirely sure what this 4 represents
45         # PUSH the next 69 bytes (0x45 == 69)
# The text
5468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73
```